# HealthKit permissions modal - Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

Whenever I ask for `HealthKit` permissions, the library brings up a modal view onto the screen with `UISwitches`. The entire app is written programatically.

Whenever it appears, I get this warning:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x146e252d0>
```

Since I don't control Apple's health permissions view code, I was wondering how to stop this from happening? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your code bringing up Health Access isn't interfering with a transition already happening.  I was having the same problem along with the Health Access modal view freezing.  While debugging I manually set the HealthKit permissions in the Health app, and this warning/error disappeared.

Since the same code is executing on my part and being called from viewDidLoad (I also tried viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, and from a button press where there was no transitions called); I think this might be some type of HealthKit bug.  If it isn't freezing the Health Access screen for you like it was for me, it seems like it is ignorable for the time being and maybe Apple will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

That message in syslog is probably harmless, but if you're concerned about it you should file a [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I'm calling the Apple's health authorisation request from an button action in swift, so It look to me like is a problem with Apple's health kit.